# Can I change the color of selected query in QGIS2.18.9 (Las Palmas)?

Tags: qgis-2.18

It is a shapefile of Gujarat roadways, and I tried to select some features which appear selected in the attribute table but not in the map. Shapefile is perfect.
Selected features are related to specific SH from Ahmdabad to Modasa.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your question, you want to change the default selection highlight colour.  It defaults to yellow and if you used yellow as your symbology for your roads, then you can't see what has been selected in the map.

To change the default selection colour go `Settings->Options->Canvas & Legend` there you will find the setting for default selection colour.